# What does it mean when a function takes an argument containing an equals = sign?

Tags: javascript, function

My function, defined inside a class, takes one object as an argument. There's an equals sign after the object, still inside the function argument definition. I haven't encountered this before, what does it mean? Does it default to passing an empty object if no email key/object pair is passed?

```
class UserAPI extends DataSource {

   async createUser({ email: emailArg } = {}) { 
      ...function goes here...          ^^^^
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That means [default parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters). In your example if you don't provide any parameter or if you pass `undefined`, an empty object will be passed instead, and `emailArg` will be `undefined` as an empty object doesn't contain any `email` property:

```js
console.log({}.email);
```

Comment: This is the exact answer. Also a note for question owner, ``{ email: emailArg } = {}`` is known as object destruction or destructing assignment. Check this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: Right. And also in this case it is not required, because code would have same execution result whether empty object as default value or not.

Comment: Not really, the destructuring part would fail if passing `undefined` without the default param

Comment: Yep, sorry... )